# Dependency Injection - What If Dependency Lifetimes Are Shorter Than The Dependent Object?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I realise that DI is a very flexible design pattern, although I'm struggling to accept it as my 'silver bullet' for creating decoupled code.

**Here's why:** What happens when the dependent object has a longer lifetime than the dependencies it has been injected with?

**Example application:** I have a `BusinessLogic` class which is instantiated for the lifetime of my application. This class requires a `DataContext` object to perform database operations. I have thefore created an abstract `DataContextFactory` with two implementations: `StaticDataContextFactory` and `WebDataContextFactory`. The former maintains a single DataContext for the lifetime of the application, whereas the latter will create new DataContexts for each HTTP request.

**Problem in the example :** As you can see, all will be fine when the `StaticDataContextFactory` is used. However, when the `WebDataContextFactory` is used the `BusinessLogic` will fail, since it's injected with a `DataContext` which will expire/dispose once the first request completes.

**My question is:** Must all dependent objects have a lifetime which is less or equal to the lifetime of its dependencies? If so, then what happens when the lifetime of each dependency is unknown to the code which instantiates the dependent classes?

Comment: I'm not sure it's wise to attempt to keep a unit-of-work oriented DataContext alive for the entire life of the application. Maybe you should consider having your BusinessLogic class acquire and dispose of data contexts on a per-method basis? Or even better, find a way to make your BusinessLogic class not static, but instantiated by the web requests that need it...

Comment: Whilst I realise that this particular example can be reworked, I remain dubious that I'll find myself in the situation whereby a dependable object has a longer scope than one of its dependencies, but will be unaware of the situation due to various abstractions. In short: You're answering 'Yes' to the question in my last paragraph.

Comment: I agree with Joel's first sentence.

Comment: Lawrence, you're missing an important point. The objects that you inject can have the ability to retrieve or instantiate another object (DataContext, in your case) when you need it. Hence, the "Current" property or method.

Comment: Thank's for the comments guys, but perhaps I'll share a real-world example: In Umbraco (a .NET CMS) a DataContext is relatively expensive to instantiate. Furthermore, there are significant performance benefits to be gained by reusing a DataContext over-and-over due various caching operations it performs internally. Furthermore, a more sophisticated implementation may go further by performing Rushmore optimisation, etc. (I digress). Nevertheless: there is an obvious advantage for pooling such objects. However, this introduces the above complexities.

Comment: @Lawrence, okay. If your DataContext is that expensive to instantiate, maybe it has no place in a web application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring framework's web integration addresses this problem using proxies and aspects.  Longer-scoped objects are injected with proxies to the shorter-scoped objects.  Each proxy knows how to fetch the "current" version of its shorter-scoped delegate, via the HTTP session or HTTP request (for session- and request-scoped beans, respectively).

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection

Comment: Before I delve into this article, does this solution involve coupling the dependent class with Spring? Also see my comment on Pedro's answer; I'm aware of service location methods, but realise this invariably results in most of your classes being coupled with a particular IoC container (in this case Spring).

Comment: Lawrence, save your self a lot of time and implement a "Current" method on your classes. Your Web one can use HttpContext.Current.Items[] to store your DataContext. Oh--and mark my post as the answer!

Comment: No, Lawrence, the dependent class won't have any coupling to Spring.  Nor the dependency class.

Comment: Unfortunately, though, your application with be coupled to Spring.

Answer (score 1):

As other posters have pointed out, there are proxy-based solutions to this. I'd put that in the 'last resort' category though.

You can refactor to remove this inconsistency, and I think the end result will be nicer to work with in the long run. I don't know a lot about your scenario, but a few things you could consider:

1. Get rid of the factories, let the container inject the `DataContext` and then use the container's lifetime control to adjust the lifetime of the `DataContext` in different environments
2. Don't make the `BusinessLogic` component single-instance. If you create a new one for each use, it will naturally pick up a web-scoped `DataContext` if DC is configured that way, or the single DC in the other configuration
3. If `BusinessLogic` has state or is expensive to instantiate, move the expensive/stateful parts into sub-components that have single-instance lifetime

I've seen the proxy-based solution that can be used in Spring - it is personal taste but I'd be wary about how understandable this solution will be long-term. You'd have to be very disciplined to make sure that anything returned from the 'current web request' through the proxy would not be referenced or kept around longer than the request that owns it...

Working successfully with lifetime in IoC really relies heavily on keeping a clean separation between units of work, which in a web environment is pleasant and natural - it will pay to go with the flow if you can.

Hope this helps, Nick

Comment: Good advice, thanks Nick. Just to clarify, you are answering the same as Joel: 'Yes' to the question in the last paragraph of my post.

Comment: It's reasonable to be concerned about how understandable the proxy solution is.  But it's an actual solution, and it's the safest and most transparent one I can think of, short of refactoring your code so that the BusinessLogic isn't a singleton, which is Nick's #2.  #1 doesn't sound any safer or better, but perhaps Nick can flesh it out.  And doesn't #3 just restate the problem?

Comment: Just to clarify the proxy solution: Would I inject Func<DataContext> into my BusinessLogic? That's the only proxy I can think of which isn't coupled to a particular container. If so, then where do you stop? Shouldn't all classes be written like this, since they can never be certain of the dependency's lifetime?

Comment: The solution I'm offering is Spring-specific, although it -doesn't- couple your code to Spring.  I'll update my answer with the details.

Answer (score 0):

I have been pondering a similar question. (Check my post on DI: [Dependency Injection Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796051/dependency-injection-container), Second Answer) I realized that a proper implementation using Interface Injection would actually do the trick.

The reason I think it may work well is because while it is common to extract an interface from an object, as long as the interface hierarchies are properly designed, even if the objects go out of scope, the data relevant to the interface will actually persist. Therefore you would not end up having a dependency that goes out of scope before your actual object has been released by the code that consumes it.

In the example I've shown I rolled out my own "DI" although it is not really a true DI pattern, i believe it does the job pretty well.

Comment: " if the objects go out of scope, the data relevant to the interface will actually persist." - Are you sure? Polymorphism or not, you're still referencing the wrong object. I use the term 'wrong' because it may be that it's still in scope, but has been released to a pool and you should no longer be referencing it; instead you should have acquired a different object etc.

Comment: Upon further research I found the following: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156(v=VS.80).aspx) An interface is similar to an abstract base class. Therefore, an interface's implementator (the class that implements it) cannot go out of scope so long as the Interface instance is used.

Comment: Sorry, bleepzter, but you're mistaken.

Comment: @Pedro, can you elaborate on this? I am curious to know for my own learning.

Comment: @bleepzter, yes I can elaborate a bit. An instance of a class that implements an interface can go out of scope, just like any other object.

Comment: @Pedro, what happens to the interface instance created from the class instance that went out of scope?

Comment: @bleepzter, I'm not sure I understand your question. But eventually, whatever goes out of scope will be garbage-collected at some point.

Comment: @Pedro, what happens to the interface instance created from the class instance that went out of scope? I mean sure, objects may or may not get disposed of by the GC when the GC decides that the object(s) are no longer in scope. However since Interfaces are by design an abstract contract whose members have to be implemented by the object that uses it, than an interface cannot lose its implementation so long as the interface is used. It's not like a whole another object is created of type "interface". The interface is merely a pointer to those abstract members which reside in the implementor.

Comment: I believe bleepzter is suggesting that if the dependency is referenced from a member variable within a class (either via its reflected type or a base type) then it will stay in scope. In which case: yes, it will stay in scope. So long as its referenced _somewhere_ it will always stay in scope. However, that's not to say it hasn't been disposed, released to a pool, reacquired by another thread etc. Just because an object hasn't been finalised/GCd, it doesn't mean its still safe to use.

Comment: There is no data associated with an interface. There is o data that is persisted. Neither is it lost -- because there is none. An interface is an implementation contract, so to speak. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you ask the XXXDataContextFactory for the "Current" DataContext? Your Static factory will always return the same one, while your Web factory will return one based on the current HttpRequest.

Comment: This is exactly what I used to do. However, this follows the Singleton design pattern which has documented flaws; one of which is you can only have one factory for your entire application, since it has to be stored statically. An alternative approach is to use an IoC container and perform Container.Resolve<DataContextFactory>().Current. However, we're now performing service location instead of DI and are also coupling the calling code with a specific container (Spring, Unity, etc).

Comment: Huh? The post you marked as the answer is saying the same thing as I did. I didn't say anything about Singletons -- I was using YOUR terminology, according to the question you asked.

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood, but when you say 'ask the XXXDataContextFactory for the Current DataContext', that implies (to me at least) that I should create a static Current method on the abstract factory class. This is the Singleton pattern, regardless of whether a single instance is actually maintained or not (i.e. could be a Multiton). Ladlestein's answer on the other hand (and if I'm not mistaken) suggests injecting a factory method (or 'proxy') into the dependable class.