# Dependency injection practical information?

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container

I'm having problems getting a grasp on the *practical sides* of the concept **dependency injection** using a IoC container. I had no problems implementing dependency injection on `IController` classes using a `ControllerFactory`. This is the default example in most IoC containers.

But now what? Is it just a matter of using `IFoo bar = Container.Resolve<IFoo>;` everywhere in code instead of `IFoo bar = new Foo();`?

**update:**
According to *gor* this is not a good idea. Dependencies should be introduced using the constructor.

**But what does this imply in practice?**

```
interface IFoo {
    IDependent dependency;
}

class Foo : IFoo {
    public Foo(IDependent dependency) {
        this.dependency = dependency;
    }
}
```

## I can only imagine doing this?!?

```
IFoo bar = new Foo(dependencyInstance);
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570750/dependency-injection-turtles-all-the-way-down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing everywhere in your code `IFoo bar = Container.Resolve<IFoo>` is not good idea. It is *Service Locator* pattern. The idea of *DI* to take out dependencies from your classes. The best way is take take introduce them in your classe's constructors. And request from `Container` only root class. Other dependencies should be resolved automatically.

Comment: Please see my updated question, why am I still missing something here?!? Please note that `IFoo` is not necessarily a `service`...

Comment: Foo should be instantinated like this: bar = `Container.Resolve<IFoo>();` Or added as dependency to other class.

Comment: Lol your answer says I should not be using `IFoo bar = Container.Resolve<IFoo>` and your comment says I should?

Comment: Yes, you should. But not everywhere in code, but only when getting root object, on application start up.

Comment: What if I need a `IModel` object in a controller action? The `IService` (injected into `IController`) returns `IModel` by internally calling `return Container.Resolve<IModel>`? This implies that `IService` is depending on the `Container`?

Comment: It depends what IModel is. If it is a value object with no dependencies, then perhaps IService just creates IModel. If IModel depends on other services, then IService should be injected IModel. If IService needs to return multiple unique IModel instances, then it can be injected a factory (in Guice, a Provider<IModel>).